# NSComparator block not called

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, nssortdescriptor

I am fetching data from `Core Data` storage using an `NSFetchRequest` and store that data in an `array` - all works great. As a next step, I want to sort that `array` using `NSSortDescriptors` like so:

```
array = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
            [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"score" ascending:NO],
            [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"score" ascending:NO comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
                    if ([[[array objectAtIndex:[obj2 integerValue]] valueForKey:@"lessImportantItems"] containsObject:[array objectAtIndex:[obj1 integerValue]]]) {
                        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
                    } else {
                        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
                    }
                }],
            [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"createdAt" ascending:NO], nil]];
```

The problem I have is that the `NSComparator` block in the second `NSSortDescriptor` isn't called (I tried to `NSLog`). To give some background to my data structure, here's the relevant `Core Data` object graph section:

[image: http://screencast.com/t/AOY6IdNFWoK]

What the application does is it compares items with one another. As a first step, the winner in a paired comparison gets a `score` increment. But also I mark a paired priority, i.e. I add a one-to-many `lessImportantItems` relationship from the winner to the loser. So, in my array I first try to sort by `score`, and then, when `score`s are equal, I also try and sort by paired priority.

Maybe it's because I use `score` as comparator `key` twice in a row? But, on the other hand, `NSComparator` does not allow a `relationship` to be passed as a `key` either.

I can't seem to crack this one. Anyone has any ideas? Or perhaps I should take a different approach to sorting?

Comment: So end result you want is for the items to be sorted? In any method? Or a variation of yours?

Comment: Well, it's as it says with sort descriptors: (1) sort by score, then (2) if score is equal, sort by more important one-to-one, and finally (3) sort by date created (realistically will be relevant for items in the tail, i.e. those that have an equal score of 0 - not yet compared). Is this what you were asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second sort descriptor does not make any sense to me. It applies the given comparator
to the `score` attribute of the objects to compare. So inside the comparator,
`obj1`, `obj2` are the score values of the to-be-compared objects.
It seems that you try to get the underlying objects with

```
[array objectAtIndex:[obj1 integerValue]]
[array objectAtIndex:[obj2 integerValue]]
```

but that cannot work. So the second sort descriptor should look like

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:NO
        comparator:^NSComparisonResult(Item *item1, Item *item2) {

        // compare item1, item2 ...
}];
```

But then the next problem arises: How to compare two objects according to priority?
Your code does essentially the following:

```
if ([item2 valueForKey:@"lessImportantItems"] containsObject:item1]) {
    return NSOrderedAscending;
} else {
    return NSOrderedDescending;
}
```

But that is not a proper comparator:

- It does not return `NSOrderedSame` if the objects are equal (not "reflexive"),
- For two "unrelated objects" it will return `NSOrderedDescending` regardless of the
  order (not "asymmetric"),
- it does not detect if `item1` is only indirectly related to `item2` (not
  "transitive").

But how to sort "unrelated objects"? There is no unique solution. If both B and C are
less important than A, then both A, B, C and A, C, B are valid solutions.
What should the comparator return when comparing B and C?

So I think that cannot be achieved with a sort descriptor and
you have to choose some other algorithm, e.g. ["Topological sorting"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

Comment: 'not "symmetric"' you mean 'not "asymmetric"'

Comment: Thanks Martin, that's some answer. I'll need some time to digest and try out some changes.

Comment: Martin, ultimately you were right, I needed to write a separate algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's interested, here's how I achieved the sorting I was after.

I used only the first `NSSortDescriptor` from the example above to get the `array` sorted by `score`, and then I called a further sorting method on that `array`:

```
array = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
            [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"score" ascending:NO], nil];

array = [self applyMoreImportantPairOrdering:array];
```

And here's the method:

```
+ (NSArray *)applyMoreImportantPairOrdering:(NSArray *)array {

    NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];

    [array enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        if ([[obj valueForKey:@"score"] integerValue] > 0) {

            NSMutableSet *lessImportantItemsSet = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:[obj valueForKey:@"lessImportantItems"]];

            for (int i = idx - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

                NSManagedObject *objAbove = [array objectAtIndex:i];

                if ([[obj valueForKey:@"score"] integerValue] == [[objAbove valueForKey:@"score"] integerValue]) {

                    if ([lessImportantItemsSet containsObject:objAbove]) {

                        NSUInteger idxAbove = [mutableArray indexOfObject:objAbove];

                        [mutableArray removeObject:obj];
                        [mutableArray insertObject:obj atIndex:idxAbove];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }];

    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArray];
}
```

The reason I need the `lessImportantItemsSet` is because when I move (delete and insert) an `item` in an `array`, it loses its `lessImportantItems` relationships. This I way I maintain the list/set of less important `item`s while I'm done with the particular `item`.